# Ignoring Url Rewrite path in Route Constraints

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-rewriting, routes

I have two Routes defined in my WebAPI project

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
           // constraint required so this route only matches valid controller names
            constraints: new { controller = GetControllerNames()}
        );

        // catch all route mapped to ErrorController so 404 errors
        // can be logged in elmah
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "NotFound",
            routeTemplate: "{*path}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }

        );
```

I have following contraint in my Route

```
constraints: new { controller = GetControllerNames()}
```

method is implemented as following

```
 private static string GetControllerNames()
    {
        var controllerNames = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x =>
                x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ApiController)) &&
                x.FullName.StartsWith(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace + ".Controllers"))
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => x.Name.Replace("Controller", ""));

        return string.Join("|", controllerNames);
    }
```

Now the issue is I have a Url Rewrite rule in my Web.Config file

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^publish/?(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://someUrl.com/publish{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This rewrite rule is not working now and i am getting 404 error. How this can be somehow ignored in constraint. I tried adding ignore in Global.Asax but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added following line in Global.Asax and it worked

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("publish/{*pathInfo}");
```